# Hiding <Div> and subtags

Tags: javascript, html

I want to hide some fields of a table using a `<div>`-tag (see below). My problem is that the code to change the visibility is called, but nothing is hidden afterwards.

My code so far here:

```js
function checkType() {
    let typeElement = document.getElementById('storyboardType');
    let type = parseInt(typeElement.selectedIndex);
    if (type === TYPE_NONE || type === TYPE_GAME) {
        document.getElementsByClassName('storyboardUrlDiv').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.getElementById('storyboardSpeakerDiv').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.getElementById('storyboardAthmosphereDiv').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    } else if (type === TYPE_URL) {
        document.getElementById('storyboardUrlDiv').style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById('storyboardSpeakerDiv').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.getElementById('storyboardAthmosphereDiv').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    } else if (type === TYPE_SOUND ||  type === TYPE_VIDEO) {
        document.getElementById('storyboardUrlDiv').style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById('storyboardSpeakerDiv').style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById('storyboardAthmosphereDiv').style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
}
```

```html
<table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <div>
                            <td>OID</td>
                            <td>
                                <span id="storyboardOID"></span>/
                                <span id="storyboardIndex"></span>
                            </td>
                        </div>
                        <div id="storyboardGenreDiv">
                            <td>Genre</td>
                            <td>
                                <input id="storyboardGenre" type="text" size="20" onchange="saveAction();" />
                            </td>
                        </div>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <div>
                            <td>Ebene</td>
                            <td>
                                <span id="storyboardLayer"></span> ->
                                <select id="storyboardNextLayer" onchange="saveAction();">
                                    <option value="0">0</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                        </div>
                        <div id="storyboardAthmosphereDiv">
                            <td>Atmosphäre</td>
                            <td>
                                <input id="storyboardAthmosphere" type="text" size="20" onchange="saveAction();" />
                            </td>
                        </div>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <div>
                            <td>Typ</td>
                            <td>
                                <select id="storyboardType" onchange="changeType();">
                                    <option value="0">Sound</option>
                                    <option value="1">Video</option>
                                    <option value="2">Link</option>
                                    <option value="4">Spiel</option>
                                    <option value="5">Spiel+</option>
                                    <option value="6">Keiner</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                        </div>
                        <div id="storyboardSpeakerDiv">
                            <td>Sprecher</td>
                            <td>
                                <select id="storyboardSpeaker" onchange="saveAction();">
                                </select>
                            </td>
                        </div>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <div id="storyboardRulesDiv">
                            <td>Regel</td>
                            <td>
                                <select id="storyboardRules" onchange="changeRules();">
                                    <option value="0">Weiter</option>
                                    <option value="1">Stopp</option>
                                    <option value="2">Reset</option>
                                    <option value="3">Sprung</option>
                                    <option value="4">Transparent</option>
                                </select>

                            </td>
                        </div>
                        <div id="storyboardUrlDiv">
                            <td>File/URL</td>
                            <td>
                                <input id="storyboardUrl" type="text" size="20" onchange="saveAction();" />
                            </td>
                        </div>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <div id="storyboardPositionDiv">
                            <td>Position</td>
                            <td>
                                <input id="storyboardPosition" type="text" size="20" onchange="saveAction();" />
                            </td>
                        </div>
                        <div id="storyboardRandomSizeDiv">
                            <td>Zufallselemente</td>
                            <td>
                                <input id="storyboardRandomSize" type="number" size="10" onchange="saveAction();" />
                            </td>
                        </div>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>

                        <div id="storyboardRandomCountDiv">
                            <td>Auszuführen</td>
                            <td>
                                <input id="storyboardRandomCount" type="number" size="10" onchange="saveAction();" />
                            </td>
                        </div>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <div id="storyboardTextDiv">
                            <td>Text</td>
                            <td colspan="3">
                                <textarea id="storyboardText" rows=4 cols=60 onchange="saveAction();"></textarea>
                            </td>
                        </div>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Is there a problem using the `<div>` tag here?

Comment: The `checkType()` is not called and `saveAction()` is not defined. Are you sure you are sharing the correct ones?

Comment: share complete table tag, It seems wrong div with id `storyboardSpeakerDiv`.

Comment: checkType() is called correctly in saveAction(), i checked that. I didn't post saveAction() here, because it doesn't do anything relevant for the question.

Comment: Above I share the complete <table>-tag now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid. Use [a validator](https://validator.nu).

A div cannot be a child element of a `<tr>`, error recovery tends to move such divs to just after the table (leaving the `<td>` elements behind).

The cells are therefore no longer children of the div, so when you hide the div there is no visible effect.

Write valid HTML instead.

If you want to target some, but not all, of the cells in a row, then you have to target them individually. There is no markup up you can use to group them.